# node.js bind callback issue

Tags: node.js, bind

I have the following code :

```
let bindings = 
{
    on : (messageName,callback) =>
    {
        bindings[messageName] = callback
    }
}


bindings.on('test',(params) =>
{
    setTimeout( () =>
    {
        console.log("call id " , params.callId)
    },~~(Math.random()*100))
})

let data = {callId : 1 }


for (let i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    bindings['test'](data)
    data.callId++
}
```

it produces the output

```
call id 6
call id 6
call id 6
call id 6
call id 6
call id 6
```

I know this issue can be solved with a bind https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind , but I cannot find the correct way to implement this and keep the actual design

adding a const fix the issue but I would like to find a more elegant/generic way to fix the issue

```
bindings.on('test',(params) =>
{
    const callId = params.callId 
    setTimeout( () =>
    {
        console.log("call id " , callId)
    },~~(Math.random()*100))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is less about the implementation of your event logic but on the invocation of it using a reference that is being updated by a loop.

Since the implementation is an async execution due to the internal `setTimeout`, the invocation loop executes completely before the first event logic is executed. So because the input, `params` is a reference to the object `data`, when the loop is completed the `callId` value is now 6 which when referenced by any of the async calls will be that value.

Essentially the `for` loop is queuing up 5 async operations where each one is using the same referenced object, `data`. The loop is also updating a property value of the `data` object for each iteration. Because of how JavaScript handles asynchronous operations, the loop will complete before any of the asynchronous operations begin because it is still following the initial synchronous execution of the script.

One way to get around this is to create a new input object for each loop iteration:

```js
let bindings = {
  on: (messageName, callback) => {
    bindings[messageName] = callback
  }
}

bindings.on('test', (params) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("call id ", params.callId)
  }, ~~(Math.random() * 100));
});

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  bindings['test']({callId: i + 1});
}
```

Comment: thanks Jason. actually the sample is just of a proof of concept, the real code use a websocket and async i/o in redis, but I managed to fix by copying my parameters object , it fixes isses when async code is used in the bindings.